# Creating a new array from an object that has multiple values per key

Tags: javascript, arrays

I currently have an object that looks like:

```
var account = [
{"Id":"A1",
"item":"123,456,789"}
];
```

Since the object above has the key `item` with multiple values separated by `,`, I'd like to create a new array with:

```
[{"Id":"A1",
"item":"123"},
{"Id":"A1",
"item":"456"},
{"Id":"A1",
"item":"789"}
]
```

I'm not sure if there's a function for this specific type of array split, since the value of the key `item` is separated by commas.

Comment: have you tried `account.item.split(',')`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [`Array.flatMap()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) along with [`String.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) and [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to get the desired result.

```js
const account = [ { "Id":"A1", "item":"123,456,789" } ];

const result = account.flatMap(({ Id, item }) => { 
    return item.split(',').map(item => ({ Id, item }))
});

console.log('Result:', result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Answer (score 0):

account.item.split(',') see this it should work

Comment: Ok... you get an array. Then what?

Answer (score 0):

This is a readable response I think.

```js
function format(account) {
  let array = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < account.length; i++) {
    let item = account[i].item.split(',');
    for (let j = 0; j < item.length; j++) {
      array.push({ Id: account[i].Id, item: item[j] });
    }
  }
  return array;
}
```